# Duplicates removal using Group By, Rank, Row_Number

Tags: sql-server, group-by, duplicates, ranking, row-number

I have two tables. One is CustomerOrders and the other is OrderCustomerRef - lookup table.

Both tables have one-to-many relationship - one customer may be associated with multiple orders.

CustomerOrders table has duplicate Customers (same LName, FName, Email). But they have different Cust_IDs.

I need to merge all duplicate contacts in the base Customer table (one-to-one). (this table is not shown here).

**Step 1:**

Need to find out which Cust_ID should be merged into which corresponding duplicate Customer(s) (same LName, FName, Email). A Contact with latest Order_Date should win over it's corresponding duplicate counterpart (Customer). An exception will be for VIP Customers - they should always be the winning ones regardless of an Order_Date.

**Step 2:**
Updated OrderCustomerRef table: replace all losing duplicate Cust_IDs with the winning Cust_IDs.

**Step 3:**
Delete all losing Contacts from the base Customer table (no in the current scope. I will do it myself).

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#table') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #table;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CustomerOrders') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #CustomerOrders;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#OrderCustomerRef') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #OrderCustomerRef;

CREATE TABLE #CustomerOrders 
(
[PK_ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
Cust_ID INT NOT NULL, 
LName VARCHAR(100) NULL, 
FName VARCHAR(100) NULL, 
[Customer_E-mail] VARCHAR(100) NULL,
Order_Date DATETIME NULL,
Customer_Source VARCHAR(100) NULL,
CustomerType VARCHAR(100) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #CustomerOrders (Cust_ID, LName, FName, [Customer_E-mail], Order_Date, Customer_Source, CustomerType)
VALUES 
(1, 'John', 'Smith', 'JSmith@email.com', '2018-11-10 01:40:55.150', 'XYZ Company', 'Regular'),
(2, 'John', 'Smith', 'JSmith@email.com', '2018-10-10 05:05:55.150', 'Internet', 'VIP'),
(3, 'Adam', 'Burns', 'ABurns@email.com', '2017-05-05 00:00:00.000', 'XYZ Company','Regular'),
(3, 'Adam', 'Burns', 'ABurns@email.com', '2017-05-05 00:00:00.000', 'XYZ Company','VIP'),
(4, 'Adam', 'Burns', 'ABurns@email.com', '2017-05-05 00:00:00.000', 'Internet','Regular'),
(5, 'Adam', 'Burns', 'ABurns@email.com', '2017-05-05 00:00:00.000', 'Internet','VIP'),
(6, 'James', 'Snatcher', 'JSnatcher@email.com', '2019-07-07 00:00:00.000', 'XYZ Company', 'Regular'),
(7, 'James', 'Snatcher', 'JSnatcher@email.com', '2019-07-07 00:00:00.000', 'Internet','Regular'),
(9, 'Thomas', 'Johnson', 'TJohnson@email.com', '2016-05-01 00:00:00.000', 'Internet','Regular'),
(9, 'Thomas', 'Johnson', 'TJohnson@email.com', '2015-04-01 00:00:00.000', 'Internet','Regular'),
(10, 'Thomas', 'Johnson', 'TJohnson@email.com', '2014-03-01 00:00:00.000', 'Internet','Regular'),
(11, 'Thomas', 'Johnson', 'TJohnson@email.com', '2013-02-01 00:00:00.000', 'XYZ Company','Regular'),
(12, 'Peter', 'McDonald', 'PMcDonald@email.com', '2013-02-01 00:00:00.000', 'XYZ Company','Regular'),
(13, 'Jose', 'Mainster', 'JMainster@email.com', '2013-02-01 00:00:00.000', 'Internet','Regular'),
(14, 'Kevin', 'Digginton', 'KDigginton@email.com', '2013-02-01 00:00:00.000', 'Internet','Regular'),
(14, 'Kevin', 'Digginton', 'KDigginton@email.com', '2015-09-03 00:00:00.000', 'Internet','Regular')

CREATE TABLE #OrderCustomerRef
(
    Raw_PK INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    OrderID INT NOT NULL, 
    Cust_ID INT NULL, 
    OrderType VARCHAR(100) NULL
)

    INSERT INTO #OrderCustomerRef (OrderID, Cust_ID, OrderType)
    VALUES 
    (1,1,'Online'),
    (2,2,'Online'),
    (3,3,'Online'),
    (4,3,'Online'),
    (5,4,'In Store'),
    (6,5,'Online'),
    (7,6,'Online'),
    (8,7,'In Store'),
    (9,9,'Online'),
    (10,9,'Online'),
    (11,10,'In Store'),
    (12,11,'Online'),
    (13,12,'Online'),
    (14,13,'Online'),
    (15,14,'Online'),
    (16,14,'In Store')

    -- SELECT * FROM #OrderCustomerRef

    SELECT *,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FName, LName, [Customer_E-mail], Customer_Source ORDER BY Order_Date DESC) AS Rank_1,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FName, LName, [Customer_E-mail], Customer_Source ORDER BY Order_Date, CustomerType DESC ) AS Rank_CustType,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Cust_ID, FName, LName, [Customer_E-mail], Customer_Source ORDER BY Order_Date, CustomerType DESC ) AS Rank_CustID,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FName, LName, [Customer_E-mail] ORDER BY Order_Date DESC) AS Rank_2,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FName, LName, [Customer_E-mail] ORDER BY Cust_ID) AS Rank_3
    FROM #CustomerOrders
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT SHOULD LOOK LIKE:**

***exception:**
- **losing Customer IDs** 1, 3 (should be winning, but since there is a duplicate counterpart it's a VIP it's losing)
- **winning Customer IDs** 2, 5 (because it's a VIP, subject to exception)

Eg.: All occurences of Cust_ID of John Smith with Cust_ID of **1** in the ##OrderCustomerRef should be replaced with John Smith with Cust_ID of **2**, all occurances of Cust_ID of Adam Burns with Cust_ID of 3 should be replaced with Adam Burns with Cust_ID of 5

**general rule:**
- **losing Customer IDs** 7, 10, 11, 4
- **winning Customer IDs** 6, 9, 12, 13, 14

Eg.: All occurences of Cust_ID of 7 in the ##OrderCustomerRef should be replaced with 6, all occurances of Cust_ID of 10 should be replaced with 9*

**Eventually I should have only Customer IDs 6, 9, 12, 13, 14, 2, 5 in the ##OrderCustomerRef table**

Using Rank_CustType_1, column_1, column_2 I can figure out Step 1.
But I still have a problem with Step 2 - updating OrderCustomerRef table as such: all losing Cust_IDs should be replaced with corresponding duplicate winning Cust_IDs.

I've tried this. But that still does not replace losing Cust_ID.

```
SELECT *,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FName, LName, [Customer_E-mail] ORDER BY Order_Date, CustomerType DESC) AS Rank_CustType_1,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY FName, LName, [Customer_E-mail] ORDER BY Cust_ID) AS Rank_3
INTO #table
FROM #CustomerOrders

; with cte as (
    select Cust_ID, FName, LName, [Customer_E-mail], max(t.Rank_CustType_1) as Rank_CustType_1
    ,(select distinct Cust_ID from #table a where a.Cust_ID = t.Cust_ID and Rank_3 = 1) column_1
    ,(select distinct Cust_ID from #table a where a.Cust_ID = t.Cust_ID and Rank_3 <> 1) column_2

from #table t
group by Cust_ID, FName, LName, [Customer_E-mail]
    )

    update b
    set Cust_ID = case  
    when b.Cust_ID = cte.Cust_ID and
     b.Cust_ID = ISNULL(cte.column_1,'') and Rank_CustType_1 != 1 then b.Cust_ID 
    when b.Cust_ID = cte.Cust_ID and
     b.Cust_ID = ISNULL(cte.column_2,'') and Rank_CustType_1 != 1 then cte.column_2     
    when b.Cust_ID = cte.Cust_ID and Rank_CustType_1 = 1 and cte.column_1 is null and cte.column_2 is not null then cte.column_2
    when b.Cust_ID = cte.Cust_ID and Rank_CustType_1 = 1 and cte.column_1 is not null and cte.column_2 is null then cte.column_1 
    end  
    from #OrderCustomerRef b
    inner join cte on b.Cust_ID = cte.Cust_ID;

    select * from #OrderCustomerRef;
```

Comment: Hi enigama, you can try using CTE (Common Table Expression), please follow this article for removing duplicate records from table in SQL server : https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/2019/01/delete-remove-duplicate-records-from-table-using-cte-common-table-expression-sql-server.html

Comment: You also can remove duplicate records from your table Using UNION And EXCEPT Operator. Please follow this article for example.

Link https://coding-vila.blogspot.com/2018/12/sql-server-remove-duplicate-records-from-table-using-union-and-except-operator.html

Comment: How should your result set look once everything is done?

Comment: Hi Antoine, I'm adding the desired output to my post to answer you question.

Comment: @AntoineHernandez, I;ve added section in my question to answer your question. please reference this DESIRED OUTPUT SHOULD LOOK LIKE above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what information you provided, I used the following CTE to show the results that look to get what you want:

```
WITH DaCTE -- To rank the existing rows
AS  (
        SELECT pk_ID
            , cust_ID
            , fname
            , lname
            , [customer_e-mail]
            , Order_Date
            , Customer_Source
            , customertype
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fname, lname, [customer_e-mail] ORDER BY customertype DESC, order_date DESC, cust_id) as RankYo -- Orders by the criteria provided but while you suggested 3 should lose to 5, they have the same criteria so either one could win based on ordering
        FROM #customerorders
    )
, NewSource -- To show winning Customer ID next to Original ID
AS  (
        SELECT co.pk_ID
            , DaCTE.cust_ID as NewCustomerID
            , co.cust_ID as OriginalCustomerID
            , co.fname
            , co.lname
            , co.[customer_e-mail]
            , co.Order_Date
            , co.Customer_Source
            , co.customertype
        FROM DaCTE
        INNER JOIN #CustomerOrders as co
            ON co.fname = DaCTE.FName
            AND co.lname = DaCTE.LName
            AND co.[customer_e-mail] = DaCTE.[Customer_E-mail]
        WHERE DaCTE.RankYo = 1 -- filter to show only the winning IDs based on resulting rank from previous CTE
    )
SELECT *
/*UPDATE ocr --commented out so you can see the results before running update
SET ocr.Cust_ID = ns.NewCustomerID*/
FROM #OrderCustomerRef as ocr
INNER JOIN NewSource as ns
    ON ns.OriginalCustomerID = ocr.Cust_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this using CTE(Common Table Expression) as explained Antoine Hernandez in the above answer and you also can remove duplicates from the table using UNION And EXCEPT Operator.

**i.g** Using EXCEPT Operator

```
SELECT * FROM  #customerorders
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM  #customerorders WHERE 1=0
```

**i.g** Using UNION Operator

```
SELECT * FROM  #customerorders
UNION
SELECT * FROM  #customerorders WHERE 1=0
```

For More Information about How to **Remove Duplicates Using CTE** Please follow this link :  [Remove Duplicates Using CTE](https://www.codingvila.com/2019/01/delete-remove-duplicate-records-from-table-using-cte-common-table-expression-sql-server.html)

For More Information about How to **Remove Duplicates Using UNION And EXCEPT Operator** Please follow this link : 
[Remove Duplicates Using UNION And EXCEPT Operator](https://www.codingvila.com/2018/12/sql-server-remove-duplicate-records-from-table-using-union-and-except-operator.html)